# Highlight Row for Entire and other workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code which is working fine but this code is only works for the single sheet. I am trying to find a way to apply this code to the entire workbook and to any workbook that i have opended.

Its like when we save the code in the Personal.XLSB and it works for every new workbook.

I would appreciate if you could help me in this regards.

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

Static xRow

If xRow <> "" Then
    With Rows(xRow).Interior
        .ColorIndex = xlNone
    End With
End If

Active_Row = Selection.Row
xRow = Active_Row
With Rows(Active_Row).Interior
    .ColorIndex = 3
    .Pattern = xlSolid
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to iterate through each active workbook [Loop Through All Currently Open Workbooks And Modify Them](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/6/23/loop-through-all-currently-open-workbooks-and-modify-them). I find this loop to go through each worksheet a bit "not my style" that's why to iterate through each worksheet i've used this [Loop Through All Worksheets in a Workbook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/macro-to-loop-through-all-worksheets-in-a-workbook-feef14e3-97cf-00e2-538b-5da40186e2b0).

```
Dim wb As Workbook
For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
  For i = 1 To wb.Worksheets.Count
        wb.Worksheets(i).Cells(1, 1) = "test"
  Next i
  
Next wb
```

Comment: Thank you very much but its hard for me to get this done.